# How to bring up a hidden control when mouse is near the edge of the screen

Tags: wpf, mouse

In my WPF project, the main window is a transparent window (AllowsTransparency="True" and Background="Transparent"). The WindowState is Maximized. A listbox is at the bottom of the window. The listbox will go away, after a few seconds. The requirement is that the listbox will stay hidden, until the mouse is near the bottom of the screen.

How can I bring the listbox back in this situation? Using MouseMove event on the main window is no help at all, since it is a transparent window. Is there any other event that I can use to detect the mouse is near the bottom of the screen? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use a [mouse-hook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804) if the `MouseMove` event is not an option.

Comment: The mouse-hook procedure does not get triggered when the mouse is over the transparent part of the window. Any other idea?

Comment: Well, i suppose you have to find the most low-level hook around which directly gets the mouse data independently of your window.